# One click ebook

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am implementing a referral program and giving people and ebook as a reward. Is there a way without using a database to make it so that the ebook is only available for 24 days to the user? I don't want users to share the ebook PDF. What can I put in place to prevent this? I'm guessing I should also update robots.txt?

I'm using node js and JavaScript

Comment: What does a database have to do with restricting a pdf for 24 days.  Once someone has access to the pdf, they can download it and share it with whomever they want, forever.

Comment: There has to be something I can do to restrict that?

Comment: Once the user's browser has downloaded the PDF, there's nothing stopping them from saving it to their computer. You could serve an HTML webpage instead of a PDF, which may be more difficult to simply "save" (e.g. embed some JS that will kill the page if it's being loaded from a local file, or something)

Answer (score 0):

Save file as `usernameOfUser_deadlineTimestamp.pdf`. Now when a user requests a file, simply fetch filenames from the folder and look for file starting with name `usernameOfUser`. Now, get the current timestamp and compare it with the `deadlineTimestamp` you get from the filename. If current timestamp is less that `deadlineTimestamp`, serve the file else show error message. Use [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to determine filenames etc.

Comment: The user could still download and save the file, bypassing the expiration.

Comment: Anything which can be viewed on a browser can be saved and shared. I have just provided a way to restrict access to 24 days.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to implement some kind of authentication to know who (which user) is requesting the ebook and then some kind of authorization to decide if you will serve him the ebook or not (not if the 24 day period is expired).

These information must be available on your server in any form, and regardless of the form it is a database already.

Now the robots.txt is useless in this situation as no crawler can authenticate as a valid user, so no one can have access to the resource.

The database-less solution is to generate a pretty long link for every user and encrypt the all the needed pieces of information in that link.
So would a link like http://example.com/gvdcwt5f23ydvuztb2ftyuzfydy826ngnuy2u2gfzgnyg2y6gn2gyf6g2f2uynfu contain the user name (or any other identification) and the expiration date. So every time this link is requested the server decrypts it and serves the requested ebook.

robots.txt is still useless as you won't have the ebook available as http://example.com/ebook.pdf and there will be no mention of those long links, no robot will bother to scan your server by guessing working links.

Regarding the handling of the pdf when the user downloaded it, you have no more control over it. You can place copyright notice in the pdf itself to prevent sharing by gentle users, but there is no way of protecting the contents of the pdf file. You can encrypt it, but once user can share it with credentials, you can generate pdf for all users with invisible information stored in it have the ability to identify who shared it if you find a shared copy, but any of these and certainly many others is probably not worth the time spent by implementation of such a "protection".